# Single "accordion-toggle" Hides After Page Loads

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can you please take a look at [THIS LINK](http://www.tehranmotor.ir/contact.html) and let me know how I can load the "accordion-toggle" hide or closed mode when fist loaded?

As you can see from the link  it seems when the page loads the "accordion-toggle" was opened while I set the  collapse to be hidden with jquery but it seems it is doing this after loading the page! Is there any way to do this before loading? should I do this thing in CSS? Here is the code that I am using.

```
 $("#collapseOne").collapse("hide");
```

Do I have to wrap the code with `document.ready()`?

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

already tested.

no JS is needed, just change your html, remove class 'in',

from

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in"> <!-- old code -->
```

to

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse"> <!-- new code -->
```

Comment: Thanks for comment but this just hides the accordion! the issue also still remains!

Comment: or add in...
$(document).ready(function({
    $(".accordion-heading a").addClass("collapsed");
    $("#collapseOne").removeClass("in");
}); ?

Comment: Ok now it is not toggling on click on the link!

Comment: Hi YeYene, Thanks for what you did but did you notice that I am using Bootstrap?

Comment: okay, i get your site's codes and tested, now seems ok. please check update answer again. on top.